# how du model setuptime for diffrent agent in service block

Tags: function, simulation, anylogic, modeling

i have used a service block for my machine. i want to implement my setup time in it. So the setup time and the processing time will be a common time.

I would like to write a function for my delay time in the service block. How can I write the function that it gives me the following output:
If the predecessor is agent A and then agent B comes then XX delay time.
If the predecessor is agent A and then agent C comes then XX delay time.... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the predecessor somewhere and use it accordingly:

1. create a variable `v_Predecessor` next to the Service block, type should be your agent type flowing through the blocks (say `MyAgent`)
2. create a function `f_getDuration` that takes 2 arguments of type `MyAgent`: first is `currentAgent` and 2nd is `predecessor`. Function returns a double.
3. Call this function in your service block delay code section using `f_getDuration(agent, v_Predecessor)`
4. In the on-exit code block of the service block, update `v_Predecessor = agent;`

The code in `f_getDuration` will look something like:

```
if (currentAgent.myType == "A" && predecessor.myType == "B") {
    return 12.;
} else if (currentAgent.myType == "A" && predecessor.myType == "C") {
    return 13.;
} else if ... // add your logic
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But one more question, how do I do if the first part has no setup time and depending on which it is, the processing time is different?

Comment: Please always open new issues for new questions (and re-state the entire issue). SOF does not work like a forum, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Also, please upvote the answer if it was helpful, helps future users with similar problems :)